# TFSDeleteProject - Deleting a branch, any issue?

Tags: tfs, branch

In TFS 2010, if I use TFSDeleteProject to delete a branch, will that affect the main project?  Anything to be concerned about there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use TFSDeleteProject to delete a branch.  That will remove the entire project.  Unless you mean that you branched into a different project, and that's the project that you're removing.

If that's the case, TFSDeleteProject will mark all of the source as deleted in the project, but will not remove it from source control.  Your only risk would be if someone was able to merge all of those deletes down into the main project, which, once the TFSDeleteProject is completed, they should be unable to do from within the Source Code Explorer.